# Speed up d3 force layout with many nodes and links

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, force-layout

I wanted to produce a visualization that contains a good deal of nodes with the d3 force layout (more than 500 hundred nodes). While it is working correctly with as much as 200 hundred nodes it gets very slow with about 500, in the sense that the layout hiccups from one frame to the next and events like mouseover on nodes are far from being responsive. This made me ask several questions.

- Is there some kind of limit in the number of nodes after which it is not recommended to use the force layout ? If so, is there any other library that could handle the job ?
- If I wanted to speed up the process with d3, which parts should be optimized ? I tried keeping the use of css/attributes markup minimal (just gave a radius and a fill color to nodes + stroke-width and stroke color to links) and reduce the use of interaction (mouseover events) but could there be any more optimization done to the force object which holds all of the information ? The size of data must play a certain role...

Thank you for your input !

Comment: You could try handling not every `tick` event, but only every, say, 10th.

Comment: It does seem lighter for the computer (i.e it doesn't ventilate the way it did before !) and it is faster to render. Now if you wanted a fluid layout, that wouldn't be the way to go. Do you have any idea how it could be achieved ?

Comment: Simply use a transition instead of just setting the new positions. Note that this will come with a performance penalty though.

Comment: That's a neat way or solving the problem ! It is slower but fluid, so now there is a trade-off : fast and hiccup-y rendering or slow and fluid.

Comment: You could even adapt the number of skipped events dynamically, i.e. fewer to start with when more is happening and more as the layout settles down.

Comment: Do we have any information on the frequency of tick events ? or is it directly just linked with GPU cycles and refreshes whenever it can ?

Comment: It basically triggers as often as possible, i.e. when the calculations for the next step are done.

Comment: With more precise control over when `tick` occurs you could set up the transition duration accordingly and fine-tune when to apply it. I have tried to create a function `myTick` that I repeatedly call every x milliseconds and set the transition duration to x, but it's not really helping, some objects' position get updated while others stay the same so nodes and links are sometimes disconnected. I guess it occurs because I am calling this function while the force (not Star Wars) recomputes the nodes' and links' position.

Comment: You could do it the other way -- start a transition with a specified duration and ignore and tick events that occur while it's running.

Comment: Are you familiar with the profiling tools in Chrome? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling.  They're quite powerful and can save a boatload of time and effort by helping to target changes at the worst problems first.

Comment: Elijah Meeks' new book has sections on optimization--not a lot, but some suggestions that look useful.  Some browsers may be faster than others, too, if you can impose a choice on users.  For some purposes, you might be able to use D3 with canvas rather than SVG, which should be faster for many objects, as I understand it, if Canvas will do what you need.  Roughly, SVG keeps track of individual SVG objects, whereas Canvas keeps track of pixels or something analogous to pixels.  So increasing the number of objects has a big effect on SVG but not Canvas.  However, Canvas has some limitations.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I know you don't need points, and you haven't provided a code snippet, etc., but this intermittent-tick-plus-transition solution is so cool that I feel it deserves the emphasis of being an Answer.  To have this idea spread across a series of comments doesn't do justice to its significance.

Comment: Barnab, one more point about canvas and [Meeks' book](http://www.manning.com/meeks/) that might be valuable.  Canvas doesn't allow the same kind of interactivity that SVG allows.  In chapter 11 Meeks discusses ways of combining SVG and canvas to provide interactivity with large amounts of data; section 11.2 discusses doing this with a force layout that puts nodes in SVG and links in canvas--a method that he used [here](http://emeeks.github.io/introspect/block_block.html).  This strategy obviously requires more work than using SVG alone.

Comment: @Mars Ok, will add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to handle not every `tick` event, but only a fraction of them, e.g. skipping a specified number or dynamically adapting the number of events depending on other considerations.

If you want smooth movements, add a transition between the positions set in the handled `tick` events. You can of course combine these ideas as well and skip events while the transition is running, handling the first one after it has been completed.