# How to avoid sluggish d3 force layout on Android?

Tags: android, d3.js, force-layout

We're using a `d3.layout.force` on a web app, and I've been investigating a bug report that it is sluggish on Android: it feels like the nodes are in oil, compared to how it works on desktop browsers, or iOS.

(By the way, we only ever have between 4 and 9 nodes, and the sluggishness does not feel different between 4 and 9.)

We set `size()`, `linkDistance()` and `charge()`; so we're using the defaults for friction, theta, alpha, gravity, etc. I experimented with these to try and reproduce the effect on desktop, but couldn't.  (`friction(0.67)`, instead of default of 0.9, was closest, but still felt different, somehow.)

I then set up an FPS meter (based on calls to the `tick()` function). We get 60fps on desktop, and it seems in the 40s and 50s on an ipad. But on Android Chrome (on a Nexus 7) it seems capped at 30fps, and is often half that. Android Firefox was in the 20s normally, but sometimes into the 30s.

So, is it a reasonable hypothesis that are Android devices are just slower? Could there be a cap of 30fps in Android Chrome?

Then how can I fix this? I believe d3.js uses `requestAnimationFrame()`. Often animation libraries take the time between calls to `requestAnimationFrame()` to decide how far to move objects (so when the CPU gets overloaded the animation becomes jerkier, but takes the same amount of time to complete). But it appears that d3.js does not do this, and moves everything the same amount by tick, not by elapsed time. What can I do about this?

(Ideally I'd like a solution based on how slow/fast the machine is, rather than having to sniff the browser.)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311818/speed-up-d3-force-layout-with-many-nodes-and-links) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188266/how-to-speed-up-the-force-layout-animation-in-d3-js) may help.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks. I only have a few nodes (just updated the question). I'll try the idea in the first link about using `requestAnimationFrame()` to add more calls to `tick()`... if I'm CPU bound because of the time spent in `tick()`, I guess that will make no difference; so it'll be interesting to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, adding more calls to `force.tick()` in my own `requestAnimationFrame()` handler (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26189110/841830), *does* increase the FPS. That suggests it is not CPU bound, but instead a limit that Android is enforcing (perhaps to save battery?).

Here is the code I'm using, that tries to adapt dynamically to the current fps; it ain't beautiful but seems to be getting the job done in my test android devices, without changing the behaviour in iOS or desktop.

First, where you set up the `force` layout:

```
var ticksPerRender = 0;
var animStartTime,animFrameCount;

force.on('start',function start(){
  animStartTime = new Date();animFrameCount=0;
  });

requestAnimationFrame(function render() {
  for(var i = 0;i < ticksPerRender;i++)force.tick();
  if(force.alpha() > 0)requestAnimationFrame(render);
  });
```

The above does two things:

1. sets up the fps counter
2. sets up our own animation callback, which does nothing by default (`ticksPerRender` starts off as zero).

Then at the end of your `tick` handler:

```
++animFrameCount;
if(animFrameCount>=15){ //Wait for 15, to get an accurate count
    var now = new Date();
    var fps = (animFrameCount / (now - animStartTime))*1000;
    if(fps < 30){
        ticksPerRender++;
        animStartTime = now;animFrameCount = 0;  //Reset the fps counter
        }
    if(fps > 60 && ticksPerRender >= 1){
        ticksPerRender--;
        animStartTime = now;animFrameCount = 0;  //Reset the fps counter
        }
    }
```

This says that if the FPS is low (below 30), do an extra call to `tick()` on each animation frame. And if it goes high (over 60), remove that extra call.

Each time ticksPerRender is changed, we measure the FPS from scratch.